# Conditional Header component in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am using NextJS 13.0 and I am building a Header Component that is **conditionally rendering different content** depending on the user's permissions.

**For example**, if the user is logged in as root, the Header should be sth like that:
*Logo, **Root Menu**, Logout*. 
On the contrary, if the user is logged in as a common member, the Header should be sth like that:
*Logo, **Member Menu**, Logout*.

In addition, when a root user is logged in, he is redirected to SOME_URL/root and when a common member is logged in, he is redirected to SOME_URL/common

What I am doing currently, is that I am checking the URL path through useRouter(), and conditionally I render a different Menu at the Header Component.

```js
type headerProps = {
    children: ReactNode
}

type menuProps = {
    user: UserType
}

const Menu = React.FC<menuProps> = ({user}) => {
    switch(user){
      case "root":
         return <h1>Root stuff here</h1>
      case "common":
         return <h1>Common stuff here </h1>
    }
}

const Header = React.FC<headerProps> = ({children}) => {
    const router = useRouter()
    const urlPath = router.asPath
    const userPermissions = returnUserPermission() // this will return "root" or "common"

    return <>
             <header>
               <Logo/>
               <Menu user={userPermissions}/>
               <LogoutButton/>
             </header>
           </>

}
```

By the way, at the _app.tsx file, I am wrapping the whole app inside this `<Header/>` component.

I kind of don't like a lot this approach of checking directly the URL.
But I am not sure why :S

Is there any better way - approach to deal with that kind of problem?

Comment: I think a better approach for handling conditional rendering in Next.js is to use layouts. Conditionally rendering components in the __app.tsx file is not considered a good practice. You can refer to the Next.js documentation on basic features and layouts for more information. https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts

Comment: @MortezaSabihi thanks for the answer. However, Layouts is still in beta and this is the reason I am not using yet the new app/ directory